# Merging two fonts

Tags: fonts

How can I combine two fonts automatically, so glyphs those are not available in the first font, but available in second one can be merged into the first font?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is an easy task with [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/).

*Addendum from comments: Before merging, click Element > Font info... in both fonts first to see whether the values like em size match. Otherwise, update either to match the values of the other font. This prevents issues like different character sizes. This info should probably be added to the answer. – Cristan*

First, you want to open the font with the missing glyphs and select `Element -> Merge Fonts`. In this example, the glyphs for `E` and `F` are the ones missing.
[image: Element->Merge Fonts]

Select the font from which you want to pull glyphs. You will be asked whether you want to keep the existing kerning; you most likely want to select `No` here, but if you get strange results close fontforge and try again with `Yes`.[image: Kerning dialog]

The missing glyphs should be added in a few moments:[image: Result in main fontforge window]

Finally, do `File -> Generate Fonts` and export your font to a desired location.

Comment: I have hundreds of ttf files to merge. Is there a command-line for that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/iegik/47b61b41d3c2a1f3fbb4#file-sfddiff-sh

Comment: This seems to only work if the fonts are of a similar em height, otherwise the glyphs get all funky.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for specific glyphs only?

Comment: FontForge has python based [scripting](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/tutorials/scripting/) to automate many tasks. But I would have been nice to see a more detailed and updated answer.

Comment: Could you explain why we would most likely not want to preserve kerning? I

Comment: @Maarten I probably figured that one out by trial-and-error, but no, I can't really. It's been 7 years!

Comment: I merged missing font and it looks normal in Fontforge but it made the fonts microscopic at a normal font size.  Is there an explanation? I thought Kerning is spacing, no horizontal height.

Comment: Before merging, click Element > Font info... in both fonts first to see whether the values like em size match. Otherwise, update either to match the values of the other font. This prevents issues like different character sizes.

This info should probably be added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Cristan. Added in the answer. I sure had a yucky-colored wallpaper in 2012.

Comment: @Hanna you might also be interested in Cristan's comment.

Comment: This did not work with Apple Color Emoji.

Answer (score 11):

Also have a look at Google's [Google Noto Font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) project and their `Noto Tools` [merge_fonts.py](https://github.com/notofonts/nototools/blob/main/nototools/merge_fonts.py) script.

Or use the merge function from the [FontTools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) project. The old dead link location is: [here](https://github.com/googlei18n/fonttools/blob/master/Lib/fontTools/merge.py).

For more deep info on making/adding fonts to Windows, look at my other answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1381619/116221).

Answer (score 9):

1. Install [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/downloads/)
2. It usually gets installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin`, so add that to your path environmental variable(Only for Windows Users).
3. Paste the below code in a file named `mergefonts.ff`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fontforge
Open($1)
SelectAll()
ScaleToEm(Strtol($3))
Generate("1.ttf")
Close()
Open($2)
SelectAll()
ScaleToEm(Strtol($3))
Generate("2.ttf")
Close()
Open("1.ttf")
MergeFonts("2.ttf")
Generate($4)
Close()
```

4. mergefonts.ff Script Usage:

```
fontforge -lang=ff -script mergefonts.ff <font1> <font2> <font_size_in_em> <output_merged_font>
```

Example:

```
fontforge -lang=ff -script mergefonts.ff font1.ttf font2.ttf 1000 mergedfont.ttf
```

References:
[Link1](https://linuxhint.com/merge_two_fonts_linux/)
[Link2](https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/scripting.html)
[Link3](https://superuser.com/a/491086/1200777)

Comment: Should this works on linux ?

Comment: yeah, should work fine on linux also

Comment: Tested, works. Thank you. Ubuntu has Font Forge already installed so it's very easy.
If someone is enthusiastic and fluent in bash it could be interesting to make it work for n font files. But it already works as of now.

Comment: `__import__('subprocess').getoutput([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForgeBuilds\bin\fontforge.exe',  "-lang", "ff" , '-script' , r'scriptpath',  r"font1path", r"font2path", '2048', r'newfontpath'])`

Comment: This seems to work good. However the order in which the fonts are merged seems important. Also the metadata from the first font (font-family, copyright, etc) is inherited strictly from the first font.

Comment: Also appears that kerning off the first font **is not** preserved