# Link all Noto Fonts into a giant font in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, fonts, unicode

Windows 7 has various fonts that cover different scripts within Unicode. However, the free [**Noto fonts**](https://www.google.com/get/noto) provide a good alternative, covering a very large portion of Unicode with a visually uniform design.

I want to make these Noto fonts behave as **one giant font** in Windows. I know that Windows 7 provides a [font linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/globalization/mt662331.aspx) mechanism, but I don't know how to link all the Noto fonts together.

Specifically, my questions are:

- What registry keys do I need to create in order to define the linked font?
- What else must I do to enable the font linking feature?

Answer (score 5):

A Python script was specifically written for merging noto fonts as part of the
[nototools package](https://github.com/googlei18n/nototools).
It is not required to download the whole package, as this script can be found
separately in github:
[merge_noto.py](https://github.com/googlei18n/nototools/blob/master/nototools/merge_noto.py).

You should download the noto fonts you wish to merge into one folder,
modify the script in line 137 to include only these fonts, then run the script.

Just to note that some of the noto fonts may be difficult to merge,
as these already use the maximum number of glyphs permissible
in a single OpenType font: 65,635.

---

A general-purpose package that has a GUI interface is
[fontforge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/).
Its use is demonstrated in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/490922/merging-two-fonts).

From the fact that a separate Python script was specifically
written for this as part of the nototools package, I might suspect problems
with using fontforge, but if it works it should be easier than adapting
the above Python script.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried going to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink` and create a new key, just like those that are already there?

For example, I have a key called `Batang` that is a `REG_MULTI_SZ` value and contains the following string:

```
MSMINCHO.TTC,MS PMincho
MINGLIU.TTC,PMingLiU
SIMSUN.TTC,SimSun
MALGUN.TTF,Malgun Gothic
YUGOTHM.TTC,Yu Gothic UI
MSJH.TTC,Microsoft JhengHei UI
MSYH.TTC,Microsoft YaHei UI
SEGUISYM.TTF,Segoe UI Symbol
```

It is just the filename and the name of the font, separated with a comma.

Source: [Fontlink for CJK on English Windows 10](https://shajisoft.com/shajisoft_wp/fontlink-for-cjk-on-english-windows-10/).

Comment: I have followed the exact steps listed in your answer, but Windows simply refuses to recognise the font-linking and renders glyphs from other scripts in their fallback fonts (not the Noto fonts). Is there something else that I need to do to *enable* font-linking in the first place?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you tested and what the entry in the registry looks like?

Comment: How about the relevant difference being Windows 10 versus Windows 7 here?